# protoc generate golang code from two proto files which belong to different package

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protoc

I have two proto src file, in same folder, let's say:

the 1st one is `foo.proto`

```
syntax = "proto3";
package foo;
```

the second is `bar.proto`, which need import foo.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "foo.proto";
package bar;
```

you can see they have different package name, when I use protoc to generate them one by one, (foo.proto as the 1st of cause), I have two golang file generated, but I have to put them into 2 directory (you can't put different package name file inside same directory, golang )

```
foo/foo.pb.go
bar/bar.pb.go
```

but inside `bar.pb.go` the import are using local import path, which is like

```
import foo "."
```

I'm tweeking several options which protoc provided, but didn't make this work, any suggestion?

Comment: Are your .proto files next to each other? Have you tried arranging the folders such that the paths to protoc look like the paths you want to get out? So: proto bar/bar.proto with import "foo/foo.proto"?

Comment: it is normally easiest to have all proto files in their own folder `protos/foo.proto`, `protos/bar.proto` and then compile. The output `.pb.go`'s can then be moved to the package you want them in.

Comment: all these proto files located in same folder (with different package), sadly I can't change that - other teams' code, they are using JAVA with pom.xml setup, seems it does not have these kind of issue.

Comment: if I can add `option go_package` into the proto file, that will fix this, but sadly I can't modify the original proto file. and seems `import_prefix` is not working as I expected in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I believe add `option go_package` should be the correct solution